# ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error

Tags: webdriver, wdio

I am running tests locally on my mac with webdriver and I'm getting this message periodically on one environment and always on another. The tests will start and then stall midway through and throw this continually. I need to kill my terminal and start over. Not sure what the deal is, anyone have an idea?

```
ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000, "message":"No node with given id found"}
 (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.92)
```

I expected the tests to complete. Like I said, on one env, they usually do, but I get the error once in a while. But on the other, I'm getting it constantly.